# iPhone X 'chin' causing Cordova app not to utilise the space

Tags: css, iphone, cordova

Nearly finished building an app in Cordova, when I noticed during testing that the iPhone X (and I'd image other models based on the same design) have an issue where fixed menus are not pushed all of the way down even with:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? I've implemented:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover”>
```

I read that the viewport-fit=cover fixes some aspects of this problem, but not all as you can see here under the fixed menu:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using the `safe-area-inset-bottom` values:

```
.fixed-menu-thingy {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom); /* iOS 11.0 */
  margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom); /* iOS 11.2 */
  position: fixed;
}
```

There's an article describing the `safe-area-inset-<xxx>` values here: https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

Comment: Turns out I was implementing `viewport-cover=fit` in the wrong HTML file, when I was building the project it was then removing it. But, this was also very helpful for the landscape mode.